# How to ignore the thymeleaf grammar check in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java

How to ignore the thymeleaf grammar check in IntelliJ IDEA.
 This picture should be no errors of thymeleaf  grammar.

[image: Example]

Comment: Please edit the question to attach the image with the question and not as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- > Open the Settings / Preferences Dialog by pressing ⌘

OR

- > By choosing `File | Settings` for Windows and Linux
- > IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences for OS X,

---

**One way**

- Click *`Inspections`* under *`Editor`*.

You can Uncheck Spelling inspections to get rid of them in your code.

---

**Other way** (though I would suggest NOT to follow this) is -

- Click *`Spelling`* under *`Editor`*.

You can remove all the checked dictionaries used by intelliJ currently.

***Source***  - [Spellchecking with intelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/spellchecking.html)